# Почему происходит считывание строковой переменной и не переводит в тип Number?

Tags: javascript, html, переменные, типы, обработка-ошибок

Есть функция перевода градусов цельсия в градусы Кельвина

```
function CelsToKelv() { //Получаем значение Цельсия в Кельвины
  var temp  = document.getElementById("Temp").value; //получаем значение переменной из текстового элемента Temp и записываем в Temp
  var numTemp = Number(temp); //Приводим тип строковой переменной в числовую
  let celstoKelv = numTemp + 273.15 + " K";
  document.getElementById("outputTemp").innerHTML = celstoKelv;
}
```

Я считываю переменную из поля Number, но если я хочу сократить код и написать глобальную переменную для этого (То есть получить значение Temp, то при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит). На кнопке событие onClick вызов этой и других функций.

Comment: "ничего не происходит" --- это совершенно не ясное понятие. "и написать глобальную переменную для этого" --- может быть более развёрнутый пример для этого? Сейчас совсем ничего не ясно

Comment: Вообще ничего не ясно. Этот код работает или нет? Сократить его надо? Что за поле Number? Как вы слушаете событие?

Comment: Добавь код своей попытки _«сократить и написать глобальную переменную для этого»_, так как сейчас по тексту вопроса понять тебя невозможно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит

Так как проблема вопроса, какой бы она ни была, может быть вызвана использованием морально устаревших подходов эпохи <s>динозавров</s> Netscape (в частности, DOM-атрибута `onclick` вместо [слушателя события](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) `click`) - в образовательных целях показываю, как мы работаем с событиями в XXI веке:

```js
const form = document.forms[0],
      focusHandler = evt => void(form.dataset.source = evt.target.name);
for (const inp of form.querySelectorAll('form .field'))
  inp.addEventListener('focus', focusHandler);  // делегировать обработку `focus` форме не получится, т.к. это событие не всплывает, увы

form.addEventListener('submit', evt => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  const source = evt.target.dataset.source,
        srcInp = form[source];
  if (!srcInp) return;
  switch (source) {
    case 'celsius': form.kelvin.value = (+srcInp.value + 273.15).toFixed(2); break;
    case 'kelvin': form.celsius.value = (+srcInp.value - 273.15).toFixed(2);
  }
});
```

```css
form button { margin: 0 0.5rem; }
form button::before { content: '⏳'; }
form[data-source="celsius"] button::before { content: '►'; }
form[data-source="kelvin"] button::before { content: '◄'; }
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="celsius" class="field" type="number" placeholder="°C" autocomplete="off">
  <button></button>
  <input name="kelvin" class="field" type="number" placeholder="°K" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

*// Лучше было бы слушать событие `input` (считая результат "на лету"), но раз предполагается кнопка с обработкой кликов по ней, в примере эта кнопка реализована. Правда, вместо `click`, событие используется другое, `submit` - т.к. использование form **значительно** упрощает работу с input'ами (возможен доступ к ним как к свойствам объекта формы)... да и вообще логичнее/семантичнее помещать поля ввода в форму*

---

Если по коду что-то неясно, то отвечу на уточняющие вопросы в комментариях. Если же после редактирования вопроса выяснится что проблема была в другом, то буду признателен за комментарий об этом (чтобы удалить данный ответ).

Comment: @Leonid, опечатка)) исправил. Спасибо!

Comment: Я тут практически ничего не понял кроме создания форм в Html, и что надо использовать формы. также понял что использую устаревшие принципы для решения простых задач. В других примерах все сложно объясняется, и я абсолютно ничего не понимаю. А так проблема вообще (если не брать во внимание устаревшие принципы). Я считывал var temp  = document.getElementById("Temp").value; - переменной назначал значение, а потом она непонятно как обрабатывалась. Все очень сложно, курсы очень дорогие например (Вряд-ли эффективные). Книги некоторые читал, там как то все размыто и без примеров. В общем сложно изуча

Comment: @MoisGamesYoutbe, _«практически ничего не понял»_ - тогда наверное стоило дождаться других ответов, пояснив/дополнив свой вопрос :) Выражение которым ты получаешь значение - в целом правильное, только оно не учитывает вероятность того что `getElementById` вернет `null` (это может получиться если id неверен, или если скрипт выполняется до того как input-элемент создан). Но это лишь две из множества вероятных причин проблемы, поэтому очень важно в вопросе четко все описывать, и добавлять подробности если их просят. Насчет курсов, вообще не советую тратить время на них (сам изучал по MDN).

Comment: @MoisGamesYoutbe, если хотел добавить глобальную переменную (что на самом деле не лучшая идея), то лучше помещать значение в глобальный объект, вот так: `window._temp = document.getElementById("Temp").value;`. В devtools браузера (F12Console), после выполнения такого выражения ты можешь увидеть ошибку _"Cannot read property 'value' of null"_ - такая ошибка и будет означать, что либо id неправильный, либо input'a на странице еще нет. А если подобной ошибки не будет, значит причина проблемы в чем-то другом, и надо дальше разбираться... Чтение из св-ва window, соответственно: `window._temp`.